# Change version of Python via Anaconda Prompt

Tags: python, anaconda, powerbi, command-prompt, conda

I am trying to download python for a colleague via Anaconda. We are trying to download the right version as to maintain compatibility with Power BI. We're looking to implement Python visuals from within Power BI. By default, 3.7 is downloaded. I have read that 3.7 is not supported within Power BI. I need to downgrade to 3.6.5 (my version that I have confirmed works).

We have tried opening the anaconda prompt and running
conda install python=3.6.5

When running the above, we're told all of the upgrades and downgrades that will take place, we accept them, they all render to 100% but the code returns/ends with "[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe'"

After the "change" we run:
import sys
print(sys.version)

and he is still returns 3.7.3

Should we be attempting to change the version of python from within anaconda prompt? Command prompt? Do we need to uninstall anaconda altogether and specify a particular version of python to install? Will uninstalling anaconda uninstall python?

THANK YOU!

Comment: I'm working with different python versions from time to time. The way I manage this with Anaconda is through different environments. [See here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can run it this way, so each version of python has its own anaconda environment (this will install all of anaconda's default packages in this environment as well):

```
conda create --name python3.6.5 python=3.6.5 anaconda
```

And when you want to use this version of python and all the installed packages do:

```
conda activate python3.6.5
```

To just create the environment without anaconda's default packages:

```
conda create --name python3.6.5 python=3.6.5
```

Comment: That should be `conda activate python3.6.5`. Just plain `activate` only works on Windows, and is the older style of activating environments

Comment: @darthbith Yeah but he is on windows judging by his path and the python.exe which is why I wrote it this way.

Comment: will I have to command prompt 'activate python3.6.5' before each use in, say, a jupyter notebook? I want to set 3.6.5 as default.

Comment: @d_kennetz Yes, but `conda activate` is *more* correct, even on Windows. Plus that way, your answer can be useful to someone who isn't also on Windows.

Comment: I appreciate the insight! I have edited accordingly.

Comment: @MitchellStearns This will not set as default and you need to activate it at run time. Try `conda update` then `conda install python=3.6.5`

Comment: What if I want to switch to the default Python installed under `%localappdata%\programs\python\python37-32` ? How would I do that?